# delete divs and a without content

Tags: jquery

i need delete div and a with JQuery how i can do it? I don't have idea..
I tried do it with .wrap() but it didnt work

Actually i have this code:

```html
     <ul data-brackets-id="19137" id="navigationDesktop" class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between test">
                                <li data-brackets-id="19138" class="active">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19139" class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li data-brackets-id="19138" class="active">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19139" class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li data-brackets-id="19140" class="">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19141" class="nav-link" href="#">
                                        Offer <i data-brackets-id="19142" class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div data-brackets-id="19143" style="left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);" class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <a data-brackets-id="19144" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                        <a data-brackets-id="19145" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                        <a data-brackets-id="19146" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

I need this:

```html
<ul data-brackets-id="19137" id="navigationDesktop" class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between test">
                                <li data-brackets-id="19138" class="active">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19139" class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li data-brackets-id="19138" class="active">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19139" class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li data-brackets-id="19140" class="">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19141" class="nav-link" href="#">
                                        Offer <i data-brackets-id="19142" class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19144" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19145" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19146" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

It's possible to do that only using JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let navigationDesktop = $('#navigationDesktop'); // Select the navigation element
$('[data-brackets-id="19143"') // Select the element to be removed with an attribute selector
  .detach() // Detach it from the DOM
  .children() // Select it's children
  .each((_, child) => { // Loop through each element of the children collection
    navigationDesktop.append($('<li>').append(child)); // Append an newly created li to the navigation element and append the child to the new li
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-brackets-id="19137" id="navigationDesktop" class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between test">
                                <li data-brackets-id="19138" class="active">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19139" class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li data-brackets-id="19138" class="active">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19139" class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li data-brackets-id="19140" class="">
                                    <a data-brackets-id="19141" class="nav-link" href="#">
                                        Offer <i data-brackets-id="19142" class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div data-brackets-id="19143" style="left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);" class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <a data-brackets-id="19144" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                        <a data-brackets-id="19145" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                        <a data-brackets-id="19146" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: You need to provide a description of what the code is doing.  Simply pasting code gives very little educational value to question.

Comment: Simply pasting code? I spent the last 20 minutes fine tuning the most precise answer to this question and someone comes along and downvotes me for it. Seriously?

Comment: [While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).

Comment: "In my opinion, this depends entirely on context: over-explaining is at least as bad, if not worse.

If it's short, the code may be the best explanation possible."